# Distribution of number of times units are chosen for a simple random sample

Tags: sampling, multinomial-distribution

Simple random sampling with replacement.

Population size = $ N $

Sample size = $ n $

I am interested in learning about the distribution of the random  variables
$ X_0, X_1, ..., X_n $, where $ X_i  $  is the number of units in the population that were chosen exactly a number $ i $ of times for the sample.
Note that:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n X_i = N
$$

If three and only three units in the population have been choosen just four times for the sample, then $ X_4 = 3 $ . $ X_0,X_1,...,X_n $ are absolute frequencies of absolute frequencies.

$ X_0 $ is the number of units in the population that are not chosen for the sample. If $ X_n = 1 $, then $ X_0 = N−1 $ and $ X_1,X_2,...,X_{n−1}=0 $

Is it possible to find out the functional form of the joint probability mass function of $ X_0,X_1,...,X_n $?

Comment: If you have $X_0$, $X_1$, .... $X_n$, your sample size is not $n$

Comment: No. That is not correct. A unit in the population can be chosen for the sample 0, 1, 2, .... or n times. If three and only three units in the population have been choosen just four times for the sample, then $ X_4 = 3 $. $ X_0,X_1,...,X_n $ are absolute frequencies of absolute frequencies.

Comment: $ X_0 $ is the number of units in the population that are not chosen for the sample. If $ X_n = 1 $, then $ X_0 = N - 1 $ and  $ X_1, X_2, ..., X_{n-1} = 0 $.

Comment: Sorry; I see. Your question could be a little clearer though.

Comment: [OT] is it a problem from statistical mechanics? looks like some occupancy distribution ...

Comment: Also, do you have a specific question about the distribution?  A back of envelope calculation shows $\mathbb{E}[X_r] = N { n \choose r } (1/N)^r (1 - 1/N)^{n-r}$ but presumably you want more than that :)

Comment: Yes, I would like to know the functional form of the joint probability mass function. $ X_0, X_1, ..., X_n $ are NOT independent. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: It is not a problem from statistical mechanics. At least, I was not working on statistical mechanics when I first got interested in this question.

Comment: Glen_b: Any suggestion to make the question a little bit more clear?

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear. Maybe just one line saying "what is the joint distribution of $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x_r \ge 0$, $\sum_{r=0}^n x_r = N$ and $\sum_r r x_r = n$.

The joint probability for observing $X_r = x_r$ all $r$ is:
the number of allocations of the population into appropriately sized buckets * the number of label allocations * the probability of each $n$-sized sample realisation,
$$
{N \choose x_0 \ldots x_n} \frac{n!}{\prod_{r=0}^n (r!)^{x_r} } (1/N)^n
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, P.Windridge. I think you are right.

Comment: No problem :)  Re. *I think you are right* - should I add more explanation?

Comment: I do not think further explanations are needed. Thank you very much for your offer. I just wrote "I think you are right" because one can always be wrong when believes to know something. You must be very clever.

Comment: Thanks, but I am definitely not very clever and am experienced with finding myself wrong despite having believed otherwise :D